# Can you, and if so how do you get the default cursor as an Image?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyway I can get the users default cursor texture in JavaScript as an Image object?

Comment: Have you tried to do it at all on your own?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Each browser is free to display whatever they want as cursor and there is no API to query what image they use. You could check the browser name and version and download the image from the source when it's an OSS project but ... yeah.

That said, you can define your own cursors:

```
cursor: url('some-cursor.ico'), default;
```

That way, you could try to make the browser use a known image.

Related:

- [CSS Custom Cursors](http://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor)